# ons-lazy-repeat で itemのidを編集したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

下記の※の箇所でidの値を編集したいのですが、記述方法がわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

```js
function funcRepeat($scope){
    $scope.RepeatDelegate = {
      configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.a = "a";
        itemScope.b = "b";

        ※ここでid="xxx"の値を編集したい

        }
    };
};
```

```html
<script>
     ons.bootstrap()
     .controller('RepeatController', funcRepeat);
 </script>

 <ons-list id="questionlist" ng-controller="RepeatController">
     <ons-list-item id="xxx"  class="list-item"  ons-lazy-repeat="RepeatDelegate">
        {{ a }}
        {{ b }}
     </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngAttrを使用する方法があります。
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

```js
function funcRepeat($scope){
    $scope.RepeatDelegate = {
      configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.a = "a";
        itemScope.b = "b";

        ※ここでid="xxx"の値を編集したい
        itemScope.id = "hoge"+index;

        }
    };
};
```

```html
<ons-list-item ng-attr-id="{{id}}"  class="list-item"  ons-lazy-repeat="RepeatDelegate">
```

Comment: ng-attr-id="{{id}}"でも、id="{{id}}"　でもＯＫでした。ありがとうございました。